# Unable to hide a list column inside the list content type inside my event receiver

Tags: 2013, development, content-type, event-receivers, farm-solution

I have the following `ItemUpdated` event receiver inside my sharepoint farm 2013. now inside my `itemupdated` event receiver i am creating a new sub-site, then inside a list titled "Risk & Issue", i am accessing its list content type, and set the title field as hidden inside the list content type and leave the settings as is inside the site content type. so i tried the following code:-

```
 public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            //create the subsite
            SPWeb newSite = spCurrentSite.Webs.Add(curItemID, curItemSiteName, "created automatically after adding a new project item", Convert.ToUInt16(1033), webTemplate, false, false);
            //code goes here
            newSite.Update();
            // loop through the new site lists
            for (int i = 0; i < newSite.Lists.Count; i++)
            {
            if (newSite.Lists[i].Title.ToLower() == "risk & issue")
                {

                    SPContentType riskCT =  newSite.Lists[i].ContentTypes[0];
                    if (riskCT.Fields.ContainsFieldWithStaticName("Title") == true)
                    {
                    SPField titlefield=   riskCT.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title");
                    titlefield.Hidden = true; 
                    riskCT.Update();

                    }
                }
            }
            newSite.Dispose();
        }
```

now when the event receiver runs, it will create a new subsite, and i will not get any exception, but the title field inside the content type will still be set to Required instead of being hidden. so can anyone adivce what is wrong with my code, that is preventing the Title field from being set as hidden inside the list content type??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{

    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    //create the subsite
    SPWeb newSite = spCurrentSite.Webs.Add(curItemID, curItemSiteName, "created automatically after adding a new project item", Convert.ToUInt16(1033), webTemplate, false, false);
    //code goes here
    newSite.Update();

    //change the list title as its in the site
    //no need to iterate the lists in the subsite
    SPList list = newSite.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue");

    SPContentType listCT = list.ContentTypes[0];

    SPField field = listCT.Fields["Title"]; 
    listCT.FieldLinks[field.Id].Required = false; 
    listCT.FieldLinks[field.Id].Hidden = true; 
    listCT.Update();

    newSite.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. now i do not want to hide the title field from the list view, i want to hide it from the list content type... simialr to going to the list settings>>list content type>click on the title field>> set it as hidden..

Comment: Can you check the edited code ?

Comment: now i tried your updated code and it is working well,, but i am not sure why you are setting this ` listCT.FieldLinks[field.Id].Required = false; ` i remove this line of code and my title field was set to hidden.. so is there a specific reason you are using this line of code  `listCT.FieldLinks[field.Id].Required = false; `??? as seems `listCT.FieldLinks[field.Id].Hidden = true; ` will be sufficient to set the field as hidden..

Comment: The primary reason i wrote it was because by default `Title` column is set to required in the content types. But since we want to hide it, i set the required to false. But if its working in your case even without that line of code, you can remove it. I just thought of it as a kinda good practice to make the field non-required first and then hide it.

Comment: I always avoid adding any additional link of code when it comes to sharepoint event receivers :) . and since i am saving the site as template, so the less code is always better.. so now final question in the above code the list content type will be effected not the site content type ? as still the relation between the Title column at the list content type level  and the title column at the site content type level is there?

Comment: i mean if i go to the title at the site CT level and i set it back to be required and i chose to propagate the chnage to the underlying list CTs , then my modification will be overridden?? and the title column and the list CT will be changed from hidden back to required (similar when setting the fields as hidden and required using the UI ?)

Comment: Yes it will be overridden. If you make a change at site CT level, and choose to propagate change then at the list level it will be changed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SPList list = newSite.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue");
SPField titlefield= list.Fields["Title"];
if (!titlefield.CanToggleHidden)
{
  Type type = titlefield.GetType();
  MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod("SetFieldBoolValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); 
  mi.Invoke(titlefield, new object[] { "CanToggleHidden", true });
}
titlefield.Required = false;
titlefield.Hidden = true;
titlefield.Update();
```

Comment: now i find this link which propsed 2 appraochies, and it https://spandps.com/2011/02/09/programmatically-setting-a-field-to-hidden-within-a-content-type-sharepoint-sp2010-in/ but it mentioned that using toggling CanToggleHidden internal property is not a supported appraoch..

Comment: It is true. It is not supported. But it is the only approach that has worked for me when the site has been created through a template.

Comment: but i tried the below appraoch  which mainly uses `listCT.FieldLinks[field.Id].Hidden = true; ` and it worked for me.. so is there any reason you did not try it ? second question, i am not sure what does not supported mean? does it mean that Microsoft can not guarantee that it will work !

Comment: If the supported option works, use it. Yes, it means what you wrote.